# image save to folder in java

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I am working with java. In my application i want to give facility to user to add and change image. I use open dialog box to select image, it will work properly i.e on button click open dialog is open select any image.

i want to store that selected image into specified folder (src/resources/ and that path stored into database, for furhter retrivation.

Please guide me to overcome from that problem.

Actual code:

```
private void btnImagenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    int returnVal = ElegirImagen.showOpenDialog(this);

    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        File file = ElegirImagen.getSelectedFile();
        String nombre=ElegirImagen.getSelectedFile().getName();
        String sname = file.getAbsolutePath();
       BufferedImage myPicture=null;
        try {
            myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File(sname));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Videoteca.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        lblImg.setIcon(new ImageIcon(myPicture));
        lblImg.repaint();

        BufferedImage i = new BufferedImage(300,500,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        File fichero = new File(sname);
    String formato = "jpg";
        try {
            ImageIO.write(i, formato, fichero);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Videoteca.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't actually specify your problem. Please rephrase and pin-point your issue

Comment: I cant save the file choosed in jFileChooser to src/resources with the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Swing has single threading model. All generated  `Events` are  also processed by a single Queue known as `EventQueue` inside one single thread known as `EDT(Event Dispatch Thread)`. Action Event is also no exception. You should not read and write file inside this thread. Rather create a new thread using the means of Anonymous class or extending `Runnable` and deploy your image read-write operation there.
2. Though it is not clear from what you are asking, but i assume that you are probably after writing an image. `ImageIO` has `write` function too to write an image file. Check out [Writing/Saving an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html) tutorial which contains enough description.